# How to get Program Association Section (Table) from a real time protocol streaming?

Tags: android

I want to know how to get PAT (or PMT) information's for a rtp streaming in an Android?
I develop an Android TV application which can receive and read the rtp streaming from a given Multicast Address. Now, i want to read PAT information's from this rtp streaming signal.

Comment: In the application, i used LibVLC library from 'de.mrmaffen:libvlc-android:2.1.12@aar'

Comment: And i receive signal from Multicast Address like this rtp://192.168.1.1:1234

Comment: I don't know ...